# Help recall the exact idiom "I'm against my brother, I'm with my brother against my cousin, I'm with my brother and cousing against everyone else"

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

There's a very interesting asian saying, describing dichotomy of a person's attitude towards others.

My quote is probably incorrect, but it says roughy:

> "I'm against my brother, I'm with my brother against my cousin, I'm
>   with my brother and cousin against everyone else"

Can you help me recall, how this saying sounds exactly and what nation it belongs to?

Comment: You're asking about an English translation of an Asian saying on an English Q&A site focused on the English language....?

Comment: It's a recognised topic in the UK. You hate your immediate neighbour, but you'll unite against the "next level up" neighbour. So Southampton hates Portsmouth, but they'll unite as Hampshire in hating West Sussex, who they'll unite with as Southerners to hate Northerners, who they'll unite with as English to hate the Scottish, who they'll unite with as British to hate the French, who they'll unite with as European to hate the Americans. The only way we'll get the world to unite is if we have some aliens for us to hate together.

Comment: A UK-based stand up comedian made a joke out of this once. But I can't remember who, which makes googling for a quote *very* difficult. But, in answer to your question, there's no established idiom that I know of for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a foreign proverb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals this to be of Arabic (specifically, Bedouin) origin. There is no single exact translation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedouin#Society) says:

> A widely quoted Bedouin apothegm is *"I am against my brother, my
>   brother and I are against my cousin, my cousin and I are against the
>   stranger"* sometimes quoted as *"I and my brother are against
>   my cousin, I and my cousin are against the stranger."*

but you will also see:

> [*“Me against my brother. Me and my brother against my cousin. Me and
>   my cousin against a stranger”.*](https://dangreensblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/brothers-cousins-strangers-the-power-of-tribe/)

or:

> *[I, against my brothers. I and my brothers against my cousins. I and my brothers and my cousins against the world.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/744666-there-is-an-old-arab-bedouin-saying-i-against-my)*

I don't know of an English equivalent. Perhaps the nearest would be:

> ***[Blood is thicker than water.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_is_thicker_than_water)***

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the saying, I was looking for!

Comment: I can't follow it.  Blood at any dilution is thicker than water? Paraphrased English equivalent of mid-east Asian idiom.

Comment: @user22542 Not sure what your difficulty is. It's a proverb, not a scientific observation.

Comment: Please, don't `-1 ` this answer, it's 100% correct and helped me a lot! If you absolutely have to `-1` somebody for this, please, `-1` my question.

Answer (score 1):

Not every single phrase you can think of is a cute saying in English.  "Blood is thicker than water" is used to indicate that people tend to side with family more than strangers, but it doesn't have the "I'm always going to be fighting with someone" attitude you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Me and my nation against the world. Me and my clan against my nation. Me and my family against the clan. Me and my brother against the family. Me against my brother.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds a very much like the commonly understood idiom "**the enemy of my enemy is my friend**". This would obviously transcend {but also include} familial relationships. It's exact origin is apparently ancient (usually attributed to Sanscrit writings of ancient India), but it is also a current, common English idiom.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/enemy+of+my+enemy+is+my+friend

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_enemy_of_my_enemy_is_my_friend

Comment: Thanks for answer, @user22542. No, the point of this idiom is completely different - it's about the way this culture treats every person, even family, as a rival, as long as there're no more alien rivals. It's a saying of one of Near Eastern nations, I believe.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood and could not be of more help.  I do not know of such and equivalent in English. This is an English Language and Usage SE site.